# Could not find acceptable representation - 406 Not Acceptable error

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am working on a requirement to upgrade spring version from 4.3.2 to 5.1.1. After upgrade I am encountering **406 Not Acceptable** for JSON response.

I debugged the **AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor** class and found there is slight difference in implementation of **writeWithMessageConverters** method between 4.x and 5.x version of spring.

```
MediaType selectedMediaType = null;
MediaType contentType = outputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType();
if (contentType != null && contentType.isConcrete()) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Found 'Content-Type:" + contentType + "' in response");
    }
    selectedMediaType = contentType;
}
```

In the above implementation, ContentType is always coming as **text/html;charset=UTF-8** even after setting the producer as "application/json". Can any body please help me understand why its not working and how to resolve this.

```
@RequestMapping (value ="/BuyerListForAutocompleteQuery.af" produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody JSONObject getBuyerListForAutocompleteQuery(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
   //actual impl goes here
   jsonObject.element("query", query);
   jsonObject.element("suggestions", suggestions);
   jsonObject.element("data", data);
   return jsonObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring 4.x response Content Type is taken from request Header where as in Spring 5.x it is now taken from response Header. That's only the difference in code.

```
//Spring 5.x new code
MediaType selectedMediaType = null;
MediaType contentType = outputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType();
if (contentType != null && contentType.isConcrete()) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Found 'Content-Type:" + contentType + "' in response");
    }
    selectedMediaType = contentType;
}
```

In my application, we are explicitly setting the response type as **text/html;charset=UTF-8** (which was never a problem for spring 4.x). After removing this the error gone.